# ASP.Net MVC: Building a gridview in the view from the result of a LINQ query in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have seen many examples that claim to solve this issue but none of them address that the controller and view are in 2 different places. This is confusing to deal with for myself and I suspect some other ASP newbies.

NOTE: I am NOT coming from webforms. I have never used webforms nor do I intend to. Please read the question carefully.

#### Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<CovidAppV5.ViewModel.COVIDvm>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<h2>Report</h2>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

#### ReportController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Phone1)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Phone1);

            List<COVIDvm> VMlist = new List<COVIDvm>(); // to hold list of forms

            var covidQuery = (from form in db.Case_Log
                              where form.Name == Name
                              join eForm in db.Emergency_Leave on form.Name equals eForm.Name
                              select new {form.Name, form.Phone1, eForm.OrgNumber, eForm.UnableToTelework, eForm.CaringForMinor}).ToList();
           
            GridView.DataSource = covidQuery; //covidQuery is already a list

            GridView.Databind();

            foreach (var item in covidQuery)
            {
                COVIDvm objcvm = new COVIDvm(); // ViewModel
                objcvm.Name = item.Name;
                objcvm.Phone1 = item.Phone1;
                objcvm.OrgNumber = item.OrgNumber;
                objcvm.UnableToTelework = item.UnableToTelework;
                objcvm.CaringForMinor = item.CaringForMinor;
                VMlist.Add(objcvm);
            }
            return View(VMlist);
        }
```

In the controller you can ignore the VMList stuff; that is for displaying a table that works now, but I don't want to use once the gridview is working.

My issue is that these lines in the controller do not work:

```
 GridView.DataSource = covidQuery; //covidQuery is already a list
 GridView.Databind();
```

resulting in this error from GridView:

[image]

and this error for DataSource:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to get covidQuery to the view in order to do this. I could pass covidQuery like this:

```
  return View(covidQuery);
```

But then how do I access it in the View?

If there is a different way to do this that is better by all means let me know.

The reason that I want to use the gridview is because depending on the result of the query some columns will not be necessary so the grid needs to generate with a variable number of columns.

Comment: You are mixing MVC and Webforms. That won't work.

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm doing. I have never used webforms. @VDWWD

Comment: GridView = Webforms.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for the input I guess. Wanna try answering the question though?

Comment: See the answer from @Goti. You need to create the table yourself: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110431/Gridview-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: See my comments on that answer. It did not answer my question at all. Table columns can not be hard coded in. Table columns must be both variable in name and in the number of columns. That answer does not meet these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are coming from asp.net webforms developer.

In asp.net mvc you can not use gridview as webforms, In MVC you need to use Table tr td format and create loop through each item in @Model in your case.

like

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Name </th>
<th>Phone1</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach(var itm in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>@itm.Name</td>
<td>@itm.Phone1</td>
</tr>
}
<tbody>
</table>
```

And also MVC is not tightly coupled, You need to use javascript or any other client scripting language to communicate with controller.

Comment: I have never used webforms before. I have also never used javascipt or anything other than C# to communicate with the controller, so why do I "need" to? Also, I don't understand how your answer solves my problem at all. You have hard coded in the values. I need my table to have a different number of columns every time it loads and that those columns be different.

Comment: Using a table is fine, and was my original plan. But again, the columns must be variable in both their name and how many there are. Sometimes Phone1 does not need to appear. Sometimes it does. Sometimes other values need to be displayed but not always.

Comment: You can check this link for your reference, 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110431/Gridview-in-ASP-NET-MVC